# Why is the correct answer "divides"?

Tags: verb-agreement

The question comes from an [English Exam](https://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/story.php?title=toefl-review-exercise-skills-1-19) test, TOEFL

> The Dewey Decimal System, currently used in libraries throughout the world,_______ all written works into ten classes according to subject
>
> 1. dividing
> 2. divides
> 3. it would divided
> 4. was divided

The solution is **2.** *divides*

why the answer isn't dividing ?

Comment: If it were “dividing” then what would the main verb of the sentence be?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean can you explain more

Comment: If the answer is “divides” (which it is) the sentence boils down to “The system divides”   if instead you use “dividing” then the sentence reduces to “The system ???”  - it’s missing a verb.

Comment: The subject (Dewey decimal system) is singular, and takes a singular form of the verb. "Dividing" all on its own is not a main verb.

Comment: cascabel , but the sentence contains two sentences which needs a connector between them

Comment: You need to clean up your question; it was so messy I decided to leave it because it is too much work. Fyi, there is no "if" connector.

Comment: “The system dividing” is not grammatical.

Comment: lambie why my question is messy

Answer (score 2):

> The Dewey Decimal System, currently used in libraries throughout the world, _______ all written works into ten classes according to subject

Ignore the bit between *the commas* and you'll have the subject, which is in the **3rd person singular**.

> The Dewey Decimal System **divides** all written works into ten classes according to subject

Comment: why the answer isn't dividing  ?

Comment: which  he divides ----will omitted ---- and will be "dividing "

Comment: thanks you a lot for this url you are very helpful , I wanna anthor website have a solution of skills from 30-50 skill grammer please this website contains only until 30 skill and I want a way to write sentences correctly  (book- grmmer book or url ) please  I wanna improve language skill please

Comment: I mean other url like this website https://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school tis web site contains only the explanations of skills from 1-30 skills in the Tofel test -this website is very wonderful on explaining the answer of sentences

Comment: @optimistic yes, I knew what you meant and that is why I said beware there is a lot of rubbish on the Internet. If you're serious about improving your English invest in a book, or google `Michael Swan Practical English Usage PDF`

Comment: will this book help me on a Tofel test grammar ?

Comment: Yes, it will help your grammar. if it is too difficult for you try Raymond Murphy; Elementary or Pre-Intermediate

Comment: You could say DDS ***is** currently used ..., **dividing** etc* but even then ***to divide*** would fit better.

Answer (score 0):

ask yourself--what is the subject?  The Dewey Decimal System.  Is it singular or plural?  Singular.  So, divides.

Answer (score 0):

An *-ing* word can't be a verb unless it's preceded by a form of *to be* (it can be a *verbal* but not a *verb*.)

So you could say *is dividing* but not just *dividing*.

Even then, *divides* is better.

There are some limited instances where that *to be* can be implied and not actually written or said, but this is not one of them.